# How call remove array paranthese while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How call remove array paranthese while using ng-repeat

```
 <ul ng-repeat="error in errors">
                <li>{{error}}</li>
            </ul>
```

looping through the process and getting in li. It should have [] only string is acceptable how to do this guide

```
["The password field is required."]

["The password confirmation field is required."]

["The temporary password field is required."]
```

This is array response

```
{"errors":{"password":["The password field is required
."],"password_confirmation":["The password confirmation field is required."],"temporary_password":["The
 temporary password field is required."]}}
```

Comment: and if there is single error message inside errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `errors` object contains objects that have arrays of strings as values. You can use `(key, value)` with your `ng-repeat` and then a nested `ng-repeat`. For example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.errors = {
            "password": ["The password field is required."],
            "password_confirmation ":["The password confirmation field is required."],
            "temporary_password ":["The temporary password field is required."]
            };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in errors">
    <li ng-repeat="error in value">{{ error }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simple print them like following:-

```
<ul ng-repeat="error in errors">
  <li>{{error[0]}}</li>
</ul>
```